# jQuery sort left oriented table

Tags: jquery

I want to sort a *left oriented table* that looks like this, using jQuery without any plugins:

[image: table]

Here's my code so far

```
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="fruit">Fruits</th>
            <td>apples</td>
            <td>pears</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th id="price">Price</th>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="quantity">Quantity</th>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can not figure how to sort it by lines.

Comment: Can you explain `I can not figure how to sort it by lines` ?

Comment: By clicking "Quantity", for example, I want to sort the table ascending or descending using the values correspoding to "Quantity": 4 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit bloated but....

You can build an array of objects and then sort that array by a key of the objects, here's the code for sorting by quantity that way:

```
//make the cells easier to find
$('td').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass($('#fruit').parent().find('td').eq($(this).index()-1).text());
});


$('#quantity').click(function() {
    //on click, build an array of objects and then sort them
    var myArray = [];
    $('thead tr td').each(function(){
        myArray.push(
            {
                "fruit" : $(this).text(),
                "price" : $('.'+$(this).text()).eq(1).text(),
                "quantity" : $('.'+$(this).text()).eq(2).text()
            }
        );
    });
    console.log(myArray);
    myArray.sort(function(a, b){
        var quantityA = parseInt(a.quantity),
            quantityB = parseInt(b.quantity);
        // Compare the 2 quantity
        if(quantityA < quantityB) return -1;
        if(quantityA > quantityB) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    console.log(myArray);

    //delete the cells and readd them from the sorted array
    $('tbody tr td').remove();
    $('thead tr td').remove();

    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        //myArray[i]
        $('thead tr').append('<td>' + myArray[i].fruit + '</td>');
        $('#price').parent().append('<td>' + myArray[i].price + '</td>');
        $('#quantity').parent().append('<td>' + myArray[i].quantity + '</td>');
    };


    //readd our classes in case we want to sort again
    $('td').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass($('#fruit').parent().find('td').eq($(this).index()-1).text());
    });

});
```

See a working example here, you can work it to include price =]
http://codepen.io/caleboleary/pen/mVbrwV

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var quantity_desc=function (a, b) {
    if (a[1] === b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[1] > b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
};

//sort by quantity desc
var quantity_asc=function (a, b) {
    if (a[1] === b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[1] < b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
};

//sort by quantity desc
var price_asc=function (a, b) {
    if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
};
//sort by quantity desc
var price_desc=function (a, b) {
    if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[0] > b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
};

 var multiArray = [],
     $arraystring;
function sortByLine(sortBy) {
    var arrays=[],
    i = -1;

  $("#mytable tr").each(function (c) {
    var val = "";
    $(this).find("td").each(function (i) {
      val += $(this).html();
      if (i === 0) val += ",";
    });
    arrays[c] = val.split(",");
  });

   while (arrays[0][++i]) {
    var d=-1;
    $arraystring="";


      while (arrays[++d]) {

        $arraystring+=arrays[d][i];
        if(d<arrays.length-1) {
          $arraystring+=",";
        }

      }

    var $mini=$arraystring.split(",");
    multiArray.push($mini);
  }

  multiArray.sort(sortBy);

  i=-1;
  while (multiArray[++i]) {
    var c=i+2;
    for(var n=1; n<4; n++) {
      $("#mytable tr:nth-child("+n+")").find("td:nth-child("+c+")").html(multiArray[i][(n-1)]);
    }
  }
}

sortByLine(price_desc);
```

Let me explain the code:

1. I define some [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) to use with the [Array .sort() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)
2. I define a function for the sorting action with a sort argument (will be one of the function expressions vars)
3. Inside the function first i create an array for each line
4. Than i combine these arrays in a mulidimensional sortable array
5. I sort it with the [Array .sort() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)
6. In the end i cycle the sorted array and refill the table with the sorted values

In order to have this code working you need to change your HTML with

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th id="fruit">Fruits</th>
      <td>apples</td>
      <td>pears</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="price">Price</th>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="quantity">Quantity</th>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can call he sort methods with:

```
sortByLine(price_desc);
sortByLine(price_asc);
sortByLine(quantity_desc);
sortByLine(quantity_asc);
```

You can easily add more lines and write the new sorting methods, just look the [Array .sort() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) docs

You can invoke the sorting with a click like this:

```
$("#sortButton").click(function(){
    sortByLine(quantity_desc);
});
```

Here you can see a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8g7csr2/1/)